# How to make a custom config file in app (it includes variables like site name, logos and css),to reuse the same code base for different websites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've built a rails app that I want to deploy but I want it to use different css and logos based on the "Config vars (e.g. ENV['NEW_SITE'] )

How do I activate the specific css based on the ENV
How do I reference a configuration file (similar to a .ini file) to pull variables that I can access in the controller and views (e.g. Site name, titles?)

Comment: Use https://github.com/railsconfig/config gem. I have been using for years.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options to define environment variables. [This guide](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) lists a lot of satisfying options.

Once you have an environment variable, you can import CSS depending on that:

1. Put all environment-specific CSS in files like `assets/stylesheets/new_site_specific.css` and `assets/stylesheets/old_site_specific.css`
2. Rename `application.scss` into `application.scss.erb` (`scss` if you use sass)
3. In `application.css.erb`, add this (again, if you use sass. Adapt the solution otherwise)

```
// application.css.erb

<% if(ENV['NEW_SITE']) %>
  @import "new_site_specific";
<% else %>
  @import "old_site_specific";
<% end %>
```